# dynamically change maxdate jquery datepicker 7days from first date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have seen similar questions asked but I'm not skillful enough to adapt other code to suit my code. Could someone please help me by showing a solution for this exact code? I really appreciate any help.

I have a datepicker script and the behaviour i would like is:
date1 field:
select any mindate between +1d from todays date to a max of 3 months.
Based on the mindate that has been selected, allow the user to select any day within a 7 day period from the mindate in the date2 field(basically they can hire an item for up to 7 days).

date2 note
if they select date2 first, allow a date1 selection of max -7days but do not allow that date to be less than +1d from today's date.

I have looked through many responses, but cannot find this exact example, sorry in advance.

```
            $(function(){
                var dates = $( "#date1, #date2" ).datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1d",
                    minDate: 1,
                    maxDate: "+3M",
                    dateFormat: 'dd M yy',
                    showOtherMonths: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    selectOtherMonths: true,
                    required: true,
                    showOn: "focus",
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                        var option = this.id == "date1" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                        instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" );
                        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings );
                        dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in var `today` today's date is stored in format `August 14 2013`

input with id `from` is assigned  datepicker with date stating from tomorrow to next 3 months

input with id `to` is disabled until the user selects the date in the input with id `from`

when date is changed in the input with id `from` var `date_diff` is calculated the difference between current date and the date selected in the input with id `from` and the variable `date_diff` is passed to the `minDate` option in the input with id `to` similarly var `maxDate_d` is calculated as var `date_diff` `+7` days as per your requirement of selecting date within week time , is passed in option `maxDate` and it is enabled.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/AcbUf/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="from" />
<input type="text" id="to" />
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    today = monthNames[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' ' + d.getFullYear();

    $('#to').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#from').datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1d",
        minDate: 1,
        maxDate: "+3M",
        dateFormat: 'dd M yy',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        required: true,
        showOn: "focus",
        numberOfMonths: 1,
    });

    $('#from').change(function () {
        var from = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
        var date_diff = Math.ceil((from.getTime() - Date.parse(today)) / 86400000);
        var maxDate_d = date_diff+7+'d';
        date_diff = date_diff + 'd';
        $('#to').val('').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            minDate: date_diff,
            maxDate: maxDate_d
        });
    });

    $('#to').keyup(function () {
        $(this).val('');
        alert('Please select date from Calendar');
    });
    $('#from').keyup(function () {
        $('#from,#to').val('');
        $('#to').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        alert('Please select date from Calendar');
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank You Tushar Gupta...you have solved a problem that has bugged me for so long.